# SQL how to return the latest date

Tags: sql, date, db2, comparison, unique

In the code below, I have been getting multiple rows for col0.

col0 is not unique, so for example - col0 might have four rows with the value 5 and two rows with the value 7, etc.

I want to return just one row for each value in col0.
Assuming numToDate is a UDF which is self explanatory (to ISO), I want to return one row for each value in col0 where col3 is the most recent date.

```
SELECT col0, col1, numToDate(col2), numToDate(col3)
FROM myTable
where col1 = 'someValue';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select col0, col1, numToDate(col2), numToDate(col3)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col0 order by numToDate(col3) desc) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you.  That works.
Does this code work the same for timestamp?

Comment: @TripWire . . . I don't understand your question.  You can use a time stamp column for the `order by`.